# xcode git commit does not commit

Tags: xcode, git, bitbucket

I am using the latest version Xcode 5.x and managing my git repo for the project via Xcode. The issue I have is as follows. I am working on a branch for a specific version. I am done with all the changes for this branch and I would like to commit and merge into master. Xcode keeps saying there is one more file to commit at bottom right in the commit window but in the details pane where it shows the files and the diffs, there are no files that show up. If I hit commit (including push to origin to bitbucket) the action seems to go forward and complete. But nothing shows up in bitbucket and Xcode does not allow me to merge again. And I can go through the same steps any number of times and I still see "Commit 1 file". Its almost there like there is a ghost file that is hanging around somewhere but Xcode does not show it or actually commits it. Here is my gitignore file.

```
# OS X
.DS_Store

# Xcode
build/
*.pbxuser
!default.pbxuser
*.mode1v3
!default.mode1v3
*.mode2v3
!default.mode2v3
*.perspectivev3
!default.perspectivev3
xcuserdata
*.xccheckout
profile
*.moved-aside
DerivedData
*.hmap

# CocoaPods
Pods
```

Comment: You might want to download the git clinet SourceTree from Atlassian, the folks who make BitBucket, it should tell you what's going on in more detail than Xcode.

Comment: Personally I use Tower to interact with remote repros, really like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, try to do your stuff in the command line and see what is happening.

Second, it is worthing mentioning the problem with OS X when using Git. As you know, OS X supports Auto-Save and Versions. Both can cause some -hard to discover problems, especially when rebase is involved- when Git is involved.

To remedy from their potential issue, use this:

```
git config --global core.trustctime false
```

The effect is that it will enforce rebase to stop depending on the filesystem information alone.

Not sure whether it is going to help you in your case but I would say it is worth trying.

Comment: I found the issue was an empty folder that was still persisting from a category i downloaded. The folder had its own GIT repo which I did not know off. Probably Xcode was confused. Its fixed.